# What is the difference between "As" and "=" in TSQL SELECT statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say `num` is a column that contains integers.

Is there difference between:

`SELECT num, (num * 2) AS 2num` and,

`SELECT num, 2num = (num * 2)`?

They both produce the same result, are they interchangeable?

Comment: None. `AS` is standard SQL, while `=` works on SQL Server only. I [personally] would go with the standard.

Comment: What @TheImpaler says :) Be careful though to not start your identifiers with a number (such as 2num) http://unicode.org/reports/tr31/ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers

Comment: @TheImpaler can you post that as an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: On the other side of the Standard debate: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using AS instead of = for column aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases). (I'll stick with the Standard.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. `AS` is standard SQL, while `=` works on SQL Server only.

I [personally] would go with the standard.

Answer (score 0):

AS is used across or SQL types,whether its Oracle,MySql,Postgresql,  while = is another keyword that can serve the same purpose but it is unique to TSQL.